# Android App development with Virustotal API

Tags: android, api

I need to develop an Android Mobile application using Android Studio. My main purpose is to create an app interface that has an empty space(line) where the user can enter a URL that needs to be verified using the **Virustotal API** key after clicking the "Verify" button.

What I have currently done:
I have already developed the app to enter a URL and then open it using a Mobile browser after clicking that button.

I have uploaded my exported code of mine.
[Exported Android Studio Code. (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14V7aCo5hjyirU9wWDlrnJkNzu4etlSLj?usp=share_link).

Please find the below snaps for your reference.

1. Initial App Interface
2. Entering URL
3. Output what I get

Please note that I don't have much understanding about developments, therefore kindly appreciate all of your support to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded my exported code mine and some screenshots of the outputs to the below link.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14V7aCo5hjyirU9wWDlrnJkNzu4etlSLj?usp=share_link

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).